# want to add custome tool tip to my line chart (tool tip will have some html content like button and some text)

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am populating the chart by getting the datatable as the response from other page.
so am creating json object at other side and transfer to the requesting site and their i parse the object and create the datatable and populating the chart.

```
 var jsonData = $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "getHourDrillChart.php",
                data: $("#my_form").serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                async: false
            }).responseText;

        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);           //alert(""+obj.toSource()); 
        var dataHour = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);\

            chart.setDataTable(dataHour);
    chart.setOptions(options);
    chart.draw();
```

other site where i creating the chart data :

```
$data[0] = array('Hour',$user); 
                     $getTownLocalityInfo = mysql_query($SQLString); 

    # set heading   
        //$data[0] = array('hour','Count');     
        $i=1;
        $dayArray = array();
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getTownLocalityInfo)){
                $date = $row['date'];
                $hour = $row['day_hours'];
                $count = (int) $row['sumCount'];
                $dayArray[] = $hour;

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO trend_hour_chart_temp(hour,$user,userId) VALUES ('$hour',$count,'$staffId')");
                $data[$i] = array($hour , $count);
                $i++;
            }
        echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a tooltip column to your DataTable.  Add the tooltip column to your column headers first:

```
$data[0] = array('Hour', $user, array('type' => 'string', 'role' => 'tooltip'));
```

Then, in the `while` loop, add the tooltip data to your rows:

```
$data[$i] = array($hour , $count, 'tooltip string');
```

Comment: I want to call function instead of ('tooltip string') like this http://jsfiddle.net/VxcWP/light/

Comment: You can do that, just replace `'tooltip string'` with your function call.